# Using GPS coordinates in trillateration

Tags: functions, trigonometry, coordinate-systems, polygons, triangulation

for a project we need to find a certain position. 
*The info we have : 3 surrounding positions and the distance between those positions and the point we are looking for.*

**We've got a setup like this going on  :** [trillateration with circles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRtSO.jpg)

We came up with a solution : we connect the three circle centres making a triangle , we then proceed to calculate the weighted centroid of the triangle... Giving us the most approximate locations based on the circles.

What we are wondering though is that we are using raw GPS coordinates (lat/long like you'd pick from google maps) and use these in our calculations (only lineair equations and systems involved) ... but is this the correct way of doing it ? Should we convert these coordinates to carthesian points first to not have any distortions in our calculations ? 
(x,y) <--> (lat/long)

Comment: How do you measures the ranges? Are those meters or hundred of kilometers? The approximations may change depending on those parameters.

Comment: we calculate distances from the coordinates in meters

Comment: If the three center points $RN_x$ are few kilometers apart my suggestion is to convert everything in cartesian coordinates. To have an estimate of the maximum error you will undergo you can then measure the difference between the cartesian distance and the heavyside distance between the three centers. If the error is too big for your needs you will need to make all calculations using spherical geometry.

Comment: My question about the range measuring was aimed to understand if you have the line of sight distance between the centers and your target point, or if you measure an arc distance (like using a taylor tape on the Earth surface).